# I'm having issues sending form results using polymer core-ajax - go not executing?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have the following element in Polymer

```
<link rel="import" href="elements.html" />
<polymer-element name="Map-Add">
    <template>
        <form is="ajax-form" id="addRoutingMap">
            <paper-action-dialog backdrop autoclosedisabled heading="Create Map" id="dlgAddMap">
                <p><paper-input label="Name" floatinglabel style="width:300px;" id="lblNewMapName" value="{{item.mapName}}"></paper-input></p>
                <paper-button affirmative style="color:#000;">Decline</paper-button>
                <paper-button affirmative autofocus style="color:#0094ff;" id="btnAcceptAddMap" on-tap="{{doSend}}">Accept</paper-button>
            </paper-action-dialog>
        </form>
        <core-ajax id="ajax"
                   method="POST"
                   url="/RoutingMapAddHandler.php"
                   params="{{item}}"
                   on-core-response="{{handleReponse}}" on-core-error="{{handleError}}"></core-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('Map-Add', {
            /****************************************
            created: element initialisation
            ***************************************/
            created: function () {
                this.item = {};
            },
            /****************************************
            show: shows the dialog
            ***************************************/
            show: function () {
                this.$.dlgAddMap.toggle();
            },
            /****************************************
            doSend: Sends data to the Routing Map Handler
            ***************************************/
            doSend: function (event, detail, sender) {
                try {
                    this.$.ajax.go();
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message());
                }
                alert('finished calling handler!');
            },
            /****************************************
            handleError: Handle error from core-ajax
            ***************************************/
            handleError: function (event, detail, sender) {
                alert('Whoops!');
            },
            /****************************************
            handleResponse: Handle Response from core-ajax
            ***************************************/
            handleReponse: function (event, detail, sender) {
                alert('Yippee!!');
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

While I can see that the doSend is being called, the core-ajax has a value. However the Url does not seem to be called. Nor does the on-core-response or on-core-error events being fired.

RoutingMapAddHandler.php is the following PHP code. It is in the same directory as the page using this element and the hosting page.

```
<?php

require_once 'RoutingMaps.php';

$routing = new RoutingMaps();

$routing->route_name = $_POST['mapName'];

$res = $routing->Add();

echo $res;
```

So really I have two questions.

1. Why is the PHP not being called.
2. Why are neither of the core-response and core-error events being fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK yet another Homer Simpson moment - missed out the core-ajax import. Adding the following line to elements.html and the ajax call is being made.

```
<link rel="import"
      href="bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html" />
```